# Thermal Trap Application in Core Services

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I was looking through **/System/Library/CoreServices/** (I'm using OS X Yosemite), and found an application named **ThermalTrap.app**. I have a jailbroken iPod Touch, and have installed HiddenSettings7 before that has something somewhere in it that is called "Thermal Trap", and does exactly what the name suggests. I would guess that the application in **/System/Library/CoreServices/** does the same thing.

That's not the question I need an answer to. What I'm asking is why it's there. Why would you need to run an application that heats up your device to where it gives the temperature warning?

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, since this question is the first Google result when searching for ThermalTrap.app:

**Don't panic.** It's a part of macOS and is present on every Mac.

It makes sense that a similar mechanism is present on the OP's iPod touch, since iOS forcibly shuts the device down in case of overheating.

Answer (score -5):

You have been rooted. Check your Boot rom vs what is listed on the Apple page as well as SMC. These are found in System info. But the program will overheat your computer if you remove it as it is labeled.

I guarantee you have malicious files present in core services.

I'm 2 months into a fix with little luck. Updates are blocked your iCloud is compromised, you have been hit with a strong root kit.

Good luck getting Apple to help!